# How to change content of a script tag using javascript?

Tags: javascript, svg, pygal

I have an `svg` that is generated using `pygal` library and I want to change the value of an array that is defined inside the `script` tag of the `svg` content. This is how I am able to read the content of the `svg`

```
svgContent = document.querySelector(".myChart").contentDocument
// under <defs>, the second child contains the script tag. Used eval to parse the js content
svgScriptContent = eval(svgContent.querySelector("defs").children[1].innerHTML)
```

Below is the content of the svg

```
< script xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
type = "text/javascript" > window.pygal = window.pygal || {};
window.pygal.config = window.pygal.config || {};
window.pygal.config['f2a1b172-9f14-4f9a-aba9-eff7e05225a3'] = {
    "dynamic_print_values": false,
    "truncate_label": null,
    "inner_radius": 0,
    "print_values": false,
    "xrange": [0, 100],
    "box_mode": "extremes",
    "title": "Correlate: income need (x) vs expenditure (y)",
    "legend_at_bottom_columns": null,
    "height": 560,
    "legend_at_bottom": true,
    "show_legend": false,
    "show_dots": true,
    "explicit_size": false,
    "y_labels_major": [0, 60, 120],
    "show_minor_x_labels": false,
    "width": 900,
    "force_uri_protocol": "https",
    "half_pie": false,
    "style": {
        "major_label_font_family": "Roboto",
        "title_font_family": "Roboto",
        "stroke_opacity": ".8",
        "legend_box_size": 19,
        "legend_font_family": "Roboto",
        "colors": ["#FF4A6E", "#58CABF", "#47A4D1", "#ca8658", "#FFA54D"],
        "legend_font_size": 19,
        "no_data_font_family": "Roboto",
        "major_label_font_size": 19,
        "value_background": "rgba(229, 229, 229, 1)",
        "ci_colors": [],
        "label_font_family": "Roboto",
        "label_font_size": 19,
        "tooltip_font_size": 25,
        "value_font_size": 19,
        "font_family": "Roboto",
        "opacity": ".6",
        "foreground": "rgba(0, 0, 0, .87)",
        "plot_background": "#FFFFFF",
        "x_labels_major_count": 3,
        "value_label_font_size": 19,
        "value_label_font_family": "Roboto",
        "background": "#FFFFFF",
        "no_data_font_size": 64,
        "value_colors": [],
        "guide_stroke_dasharray": "4,4",
        "transition": "150ms",
        "foreground_subtle": "rgba(0, 0, 0, .54)",
        "value_font_family": "Roboto",
        "tooltip_font_family": "Roboto",
        "title_font_size": 25,
        "y_labels_major_count": 3,
        "stroke_opacity_hover": ".9",
        "major_guide_stroke_dasharray": "6,6",
        "opacity_hover": ".8",
        "foreground_strong": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)"
    },
    "x_label_rotation": 0,
    "fill": false,
    "missing_value_fill_truncation": "x",
    "zero": 0,
    "margin_right": null,
    "interpolation_parameters": {},
    "x_labels_major": [0, 50, 100],
    "rounded_bars": null,
    "title_spacing": 7,
    "show_y_labels": true,
    "dots_size": 2.5,
    "legend_spacing": 17,
    "show_y_guides": true,
    "show_minor_y_labels": false,
    "x_labels": null,
    "y_title": null,
    "order_min": null,
    "formatter": null,
    "disable_xml_declaration": false,
    "strict": false,
    "css": ["file://style.css", "file://graph.css"],
    "tooltip_fancy_mode": true,
    "defs": [],
    "show_only_major_dots": false,
    "y_label_rotation": 0,
    "show_x_labels": true,
    "min_scale": 4,
    "show_x_guides": true,
    "spacing": 10,
    "x_labels_major_count": null,
    "pretty_print": false,
    "tooltip_border_radius": 0,
    "interpolate": null,
    "js": ["//kozea.github.io/pygal.js/2.0.x/pygal-tooltips.min.js"],
    "y_labels": null,
    "stroke_style": {
        "width": 2
    },
    "print_labels": false,
    "interpolation_precision": 250,
    "x_title": null,
    "y_labels_major_every": null,
    "logarithmic": false,
    "legends": ["var1", "var2", "var3", "var4", "var5"],
    "max_scale": 16,
    "print_zeroes": true,
    "no_data_text": "No data",
    "truncate_legend": null,
    "x_labels_major_every": null,
    "secondary_range": null,
    "legend_box_size": 12,
    "no_prefix": false,
    "stroke": false,
    "stack_from_top": false,
    "include_x_axis": false,
    "range": [0, 120],
    "classes": ["pygal-chart"],
    "margin_top": null,
    "margin_left": null,
    "y_labels_major_count": null,
    "margin_bottom": null,
    "inverse_y_axis": false,
    "margin": 20,
    "allow_interruptions": false,
    "print_values_position": "center"
} < /script>
```

As you can see (towards the end), there is an attribute called `legend` which is an array containing certain values

```
"legends": ["var1", "var2", "var3", "var4", "var5"]
```

I can access the value of the existing key by doing something like this

```
tooltipLegends = svgScriptContent.legends
console.log(tooltipLegends)
```

Now I want to replace the array with another array of values and this is what I do

```
updatedTooltipLegends = ["var6", "var7", "var8", "var9", "var10"]  
svgScriptContent.legends = updatedTooltipLegends
```

But the content of the `script` tag doesn't get updated. What am I doing wrong?

Another idea is that the content can be read as text and `regex` can be used to replace the array but not sure how do I do that and if that's a great idea.

Answer (score 0):

The contents of the `script` tag are **code**. When the `script` tag is encountered, that code is *executed* and it creates an object (with nested objects and arrays) and assigns it to `window.pygal`.

Your code reads the code of the `script` and runs it, which is almost certainly unnecessary and probably undesireable. The code has presumably **already** been run, and run in the correct context (it looks like your `.myChart` element is an `HTMLObjectElement` or `iframe` or similar, given your use of `contentDocument`). In contrats, your `eval` runs it in *your* window, not the window it appears to be intended to run in.

Instead, modify the object that the code created originally. The code's put it on the `pygal` property of the window in which it ran, so you should be able to do this:

```
document.querySelector(".myChart").contentWindow.pygal.config['f2a1b172-9f14-4f9a-aba9-eff7e05225a3'].legends = ["var6", "var7", "var8", "var9", "var10"];
```

If you don't know what GUID will be used, and if there's always only one, you can do this:

```
const pygal = document.querySelector(".myChart").contentWindow.pygal;
pygal.config[Object.keys(pygal.config)[0]].legends = ["var6", "var7", "var8", "var9", "var10"];
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Your code should work but for some reason I get undefined. Upto this point `document.querySelector(".myChart").contentWindow.pygal`, I get an object which does contain the attribute `legends` but using your full code `document.querySelector(".myChart").contentWindow.pygal.legends`, I get undefined. Any idea why?

Comment: @SouvikRay- I wasn't looking closely enough, there's more to the property path than just `legends`. I've updated the answer above.

Comment: I can confirm that this works now since I did a `console.log()` before settings the legends to new array and a `console.log()` after setting the legends with the new array. The latest `console.log` shows the updated array. However when I do an inspect element on the chart and check the legends value in script tag, I see its still not updated with the latest array. Then why does my `console.log` show otherwise?

Comment: @SouvikRay - That suggests the value was used before your code updated it.

Comment: sorry but I didn't understand. Are you saying there is delay in updating the legends?

Comment: @SouvikRay - I don't use this chart thing of yours. It sounds like what happens is: A) The original code is run and creates the object. B) A chart is created using those settings. C) You update the object, but by that time, it's too late. Instead of trying to come at this after-the-fact, you really need to edit the source. I figure you aren't doing that because you can't for some reason, but it may be the only way. There's no guarantee going at it from another angle will work. Good luck with it.